# Difference between printf, print, and sprintf in Perl

Tags: perl

What is the specific usage of `print`, `printf`, and `sprintf` in Perl?

All three keywords are used for printing purposes, but can someone differentiate it briefly?

Comment: `printf = print sprintf` ;)

Comment: @el.pescado. <pedant>Not quite. `perl -e '@t=("%s\n","foo");print sprintf @t;printf @t`</pedant>

Comment: How did this question get a score of 11, while it is blantantly clear that there was absolutely no research or even reading effort investment?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Short:**

See the manuals:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html

**Long:**

`print` is the default output function. It does no formatting but may append a line break if Perl is called with `-l`:

```
print $foo;
print "Hello $world";
print $filehandle $something;
```

`sprintf` is a formatter and doesn't do any printing at all:

```
$result = sprintf('The %s is %d', 'answer', 42);
```

`printf` is the same as `sprintf`, but actually prints the result:

```
printf 'This is question %d on %s', 36882022, 'StackOverflow';
```

See the [`sprintf` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) for more details on valid placeholders/format strings.

Since 5.10, Perl also supports [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) which is basically a `print` plus an additional `\n`.

Comment: And maybe you should also add `say`.

Answer (score 3):

`print` just outputs.

`printf` takes a formatting string like "%3f" and uses it to format the output.

`sprintf` is the same as printf except it doesn't actually output anything. It returns a formatted string.

Answer (score 3):

The others covered the main points, but one other important little fact is that you can pass a list to `print`, just like `die`. It can be convenient sometimes and is apparently more efficient than concatenation if you are starting with a list.

e.g.

```
sub log_with_timestamp {
  my $timestamp = get_timestamp();
  print $timestamp, ' ', @_, "\n";
}
```