# Splice array through subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am trying to use a subroutine to `splice` an array. What am I doing wrong?

```
$foo = 123223;
@data = split(//, $foo);
splice_data(\@data);
printf(@data);

sub splice_data{
    splice(@data,3,1,1);
    return @data;
}
```

Output: `1`

Expected output: `123123`

Answer (score 5):

The code in the question has multiple serious issues

- Data is passed to the sub but the sub doesn't read (nor use) that
- Sub directly uses data that happens to be seen in its scope
- Sub is passed a reference, seemingly to use to change data in the caller, but returns a flat list of that data

Instead, we generally want a sub to have a clearly defined input, read via [@_](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#@_). It can return its results by directly changing data in the caller by writing to it using data reference(s) passed to it, if that is passed to it, or by explicitly `return`-ing data (or both)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

sub splice_data {
    my ($ref_to_data) = @_;

    splice @$ref_to_data, 3, 1, 1;

    return 1;  # for "success"
}

my $foo = 123223;

my @data = split //, $foo;

splice_data(\@data);

say "@data";
```

A few more comments

- There is no [strict](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict) and [warnings](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings)!  *Always have them at the beggining of programs*.  They are directly helpful, save from various kinds of bugs, and generally push to improve all manner of programming practice
- In general, better define subs at the top of the program so that they can't accidentally "see" data defined before them (but can only use data specifically passed to them)
- Use [feature](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature) `say` for general printing, or [print](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print) if there shouldn't be a linefeed (newline).  The [printf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf) is used only when there's need for specific formatting

As evident by many links here I advise reading documentation for everything involved.

---

The question's code happens to work as intended, only the printing is wrong and it is instructive to see how. In a usual invocation of [printf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf), after an optional filehandle, the first argument is the format specification and then follows a list of things to use in formatting.

Since the array is first evaluated into a list for `printf` we have

```
printf @data --> printf 1,2,3,1,2,3
```

where the first argument, `1`, is the "format" and the list `2,3,1,2,3` are items to (presumably) use by the format specification.  A format specification is composed of formatting codes (like `%s`, `%5.2f`, etc, see [sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf)) and of literal characters to print -- and this one has only the literal `1` to print.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $foo = 123223;
my @data = split(//, $foo);
print "Before:\n".Dumper(\@data);

splice_data(\@data);
print "After:\n".Dumper(\@data);

sub splice_data{
    splice(@data,3,1,'1');
    return @data;
}
```

Your code is producing the expected output either if you use `print(@data);` or `print Dumper(\@data);`

`printf` is used for formatting the output. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36882148/6124824).